# Building a 2D XNA Game Engine

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, game-engine

I'd like to build an engine in XNA, primarily for a 2D RPG. At first, I began abstracting out some classes and built a Sprite class which wrapped a Vector2 and a Texture2D, and tried loading in content from the Sprite class' constructor. However, this didn't work. Now, it appears that I have to load all of the sprites within the Game class' LoadContent method. Is there anyway around this? I'd like to separate the actual Game Content from the inner workings of the engine, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the `ContentManager` as a parameter to your `constructor` so you can use this in your class. e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    ContentManager content;
    Texture2D sprite;

    public MyClass(ContentManager content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public void LoadSprite(string filename)
    {
        sprite = this.content.Load<Texture2D>(filename);
    }
}

public class Game1
{
    ContentManager content;

    public void LoadContent()
    {
         MyClass myclass = new MyClass(content);
    }

}
```

Comment: do I have to pass it from the Game class?

Comment: Yes.  I've amended my answer to show this.